# My div background image is not displaying in IE8

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer-8, background-image

I need the background image to stay centered because I am going to display charts  in fixed positions and want the van (in the image) always to be visible. It's working fine in Chrome etc but nothing appearing in IE8.

http://clients.online95.com/RzMaOxkMOC/rep_mktsh.php

Thank you for any assistance you can provide.

```
#aa_breakdown_bg {
background: url(/RzMaOxkMOC/images/aa_breakdown_bg.jpg) center top no-repeat fixed;
overflow: hidden;
height: 100%;
} 


<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>UK Breakdown Market Tracker</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.history.forward();
        function noBack() { window.history.forward(); }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="noBack();" onpageshow="if (event.persisted) noBack();" onunload="">   

<div id="aa_breakdown_bg"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've found a very simply solution - just added a min-height to css - why couldn't I have tried that 4 hours ago lol!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be that while your `div` is 100% height, that's 100% of zero. Try stretching both the `body` and `html` elements to 100%, too, and see if that does the trick.

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Also, as Adrift mentions, you'll be a lot better off adding an appropriate DOCTYPE to your HTML, otherwise Internet Explorer will probably run in "[quirks mode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html)" and really confuse you.

Comment: Height was the problem, I had height: 100% but 100% on zero is still zero - so add a min-height and its fixed my problem.